# Canvas Element-Position of Phaser Game using Blaze js in Meteor

Tags: canvas, meteor, phaser-framework, meteor-blaze

I am failing to give the canvas created by Phaser 3.55 a declared position inside the html of my multi-paged Meteor 2.8.0 Application. My goal is to take an existing -Element and let Phaser built it in there. I'm using the Blaze Js OnCreated() function to create the game:

```
Template.instance_map.onCreated(function() {

  var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    parent: 'gameWrapper',
    domCreateContainer: true,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    scene: {
    preload: preload,
    create: create,
    update: update
    },
    };
    
    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
 
function preload () { ... }
    
function create () { ... }
    
});
```

Then I create the instance_map-template in another template "A". Outcome: It gets created above all other html-files in template "A".

I tried the parent-field in the config-object:

```
  var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
  **parent: 'gameWrapper',**
    domCreateContainer: true,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    scene: {
    preload: preload,
    create: create,
    update: update
    },
    };
```

Then creating a div with an ID "gameWrapper". I expected the Canvas to appear inside the div#gameWrapper. Outcome: It didn't change anything.

I also tried the domCreateContainer-field to test if this would create a div around the canvas at all. It didn't.

I hope someone can help me, thank you.

Comment: In Blaze, any HTML you need to handle should be inside onRendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know how blaze works, but if I understand the documenation right *([link to **blaze** documentation](https://www.blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-onRendered))*.

**I assume** you should use `onRendered` rather than `onCreated`, since phaser will be added right away, and if the `parent` element doesn't exist *(yet)*, it will simply be appended to the dom *([as mentioned in the **phaser** documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Types.Core.html#.GameConfig) )*.

Comment: This is correct. On created is the hook before things are rendered, while on rendered is the hook after the first render. This is where you do third party Integration and vanilla Dom manipulation.